# Iterate through a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a `vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']` list that contains the following items:

```
[
  {
    u"originDisplay": [],
    u"destinationDisplay": [],
    u"stopPointRef": {
      u"value": "STIF:StopPoint:Q:24684:"
    },
    u"expectedDepartureTime": "2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z",
    u"stopPointName": [],
    u"arrivalOperatorRefs": []
  },
  {
    u"originDisplay": [],
    u"destinationDisplay": [],
    u"stopPointRef": {
      u"value": "STIF:StopPoint:Q:24683:"
    },
    u"expectedDepartureTime": "2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z",
    u"stopPointName": [],
    u"arrivalOperatorRefs": []
  },
  {
    u"originDisplay": [],
    u"destinationDisplay": [],
    u"stopPointRef": {
      u"value": "STIF:StopPoint:Q:24680:"
    },
    u"expectedDepartureTime": "2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z",
    u"stopPointName": [],
    u"arrivalOperatorRefs": []
  },
  {
    u"originDisplay": [],
    u"destinationDisplay": [],
    u"stopPointRef": {
      u"value": "STIF:StopPoint:Q:24687:"
    },
    u"expectedDepartureTime": "2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z",
    u"stopPointName": [],
    u"arrivalOperatorRefs": []
  },
  {
    u"originDisplay": [],
    u"destinationDisplay": [],
    u"stopPointRef": {
      u"value": "STIF:StopPoint:Q:24686:"
    },
    u"expectedDepartureTime": "2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z",
    u"stopPointName": [],
    u"arrivalOperatorRefs": []
  },
  {
    u"originDisplay": [],
    u"destinationDisplay": [],
    u"stopPointRef": {
      u"value": "STIF:StopPoint:Q:24685:"
    },
    u"expectedDepartureTime": "2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z",
    u"stopPointName": [],
    u"arrivalOperatorRefs": []
  }
]
```

I want to iterate through each `stopPointRef`, `expectedDepartureTime` couple (and not present here, sometimes `expectedArrivalTime`, `aimedDepartureTime` and `aimedArrivalTime` when present), to retrive their values (for `stopPointRef`, the value is not `value` but the second item (that starts with `STIF:StopPoint:Q:`).

Here is my current code:

```
for call in vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']:
    stoptime = ent.trip_update.stop_time_update.add()
    for j in len(vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']['stopPointRef']):
        stoptime.stop_id = vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']['stopPointRef']['value']
        stoptime.arrival_time = call['expectedArrivalTime']
        stoptime.departure_time = call['expectedDepartureTime']
```

The "for" loop seems to work properly (`print vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']` returns the proper list)

But when trying to iterate through each `stopPointRef`, `expectedDepartureTime` group, with:

```
for j in len(vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']['stopPointRef']):
```

I got the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Could you please help me fix this and find appropriate code to perform that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `len` returns an integer, so what you write boils down to something like `for j in 10` which does not really make any sense. Sometimes, one uses `for j in range(len(...))`, but that does not appear to be what you want.

Comment: this "vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']" is a list not a dictionary.. you must call it like vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall'][0]['stopPointRef']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity purpose and from the info provided, here is a sample

```
value=[{u'originDisplay': [], u'destinationDisplay': [], 
  u'stopPointRef': {u'value': u'STIF:StopPoint:Q:24684:'}, 
  u'expectedDepartureTime': u'2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z', 
  u'stopPointName': [], u'arrivalOperatorRefs': []}, 
 {u'originDisplay': [], u'destinationDisplay': [], 
  u'stopPointRef': {u'value': u'STIF:StopPoint:Q:24683:'}, 
  u'expectedDepartureTime': u'2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z', 
  u'stopPointName': [], u'arrivalOperatorRefs': []}, 
 {u'originDisplay': [], u'destinationDisplay': [],
  u'stopPointRef': {u'value': u'STIF:StopPoint:Q:24680:'}, 
  u'expectedDepartureTime': u'2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z', 
  u'stopPointName': [], u'arrivalOperatorRefs': []}, 
 {u'originDisplay': [], u'destinationDisplay': [], 
  u'stopPointRef': {u'value': u'STIF:StopPoint:Q:24687:'}, 
  u'expectedDepartureTime': u'2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z', 
  u'stopPointName': [], u'arrivalOperatorRefs': []}, 
 {u'originDisplay': [], u'destinationDisplay': [], 
  u'stopPointRef': {u'value': u'STIF:StopPoint:Q:24686:'}, 
  u'expectedDepartureTime': u'2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z', 
  u'stopPointName': [], u'arrivalOperatorRefs': []}, 
 {u'originDisplay': [], u'destinationDisplay': [], 
  u'stopPointRef': {u'value': u'STIF:StopPoint:Q:24685:'}, 
  u'expectedDepartureTime': u'2017-03-17T19:00:00.000Z',
  u'stopPointName': [], u'arrivalOperatorRefs': []}]
#I am attempting to build the vehicle dict like the one you have
vehicle={}
vehicle["estimatedCalls"]={"estimatedCall":value}

for call in vehicle['estimatedCalls']['estimatedCall']:
    print("\n\n")
    #stoptime = ent.trip_update.stop_time_update.add()
    expected_arrival_time= call['expectedArrivalTime'] if 'expectedArrivalTime' in call else None
    expected_departure_time=call["expectedDepartureTime"]
    aimed_departuretime=call['aimedDepartureTime'] if 'aimedDepartureTime' in call else None
    aimed_arrivaltime=call['aimedArrivalTime'] if 'aimedArrivalTime' in call else None
    print("stop id is",call['stopPointRef']['value'])
    print("expected Arrival time is",expected_arrival_time)
    print("expected departure time is",expected_departure_time)
    print("aimed departure time is",aimed_departuretime)
    print("aimed arrival time time is",aimed_arrivaltime)
```